# Trying to add two math results $roundoneresult and $roundtworesult together as visable text as a total in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to add the text as below to make it work but it just shows =(sum of round 1) +(sum of round 2) but doesnt add them up:  CODE

```
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = $roundOneResult + $roundTwoResult",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried the above and was expecting[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MWmB.png)

more code sample if you need a reference thanks all:

```
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = $roundOneResult + $roundTwoResult",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Very lame question. Please do some research before submitting a question to StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem arose because you added val 1 and val 2 with '+' which is working as a String. try this:

```
                Text(
                "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: 
                 $roundTwoResult Total = ${roundOneResult + 
                 roundTwoResult}",
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                 style: const TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
```

if. it's worked then mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is also correct. Anotherway,

```
// Calculate the total sum
double totalSum = roundOneResult + roundTwoResult;

// ...

Text(
  "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = $totalSum",
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nurullah Sadekin and Ashikul Islam Sawan both correct sorry i could vote in both. I have learnt another string thanks.